# Ruby where clause looking for a specific condition and nil values together

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have this scope in my Variant Model. I am looking for Products where `published_on` is dated not today, and at the same time I am looking for where `published_on` is `nil`. I came up with this but it seems like it only gets the Variants where the `product.published_on` is not dated today. and not the `nil` ones. I would like to know what is wrong with my code.

```
  scope :not_new_items, lambda {
    joins(:product).where("products.published_on < ? OR products.published_on = ?", Time.zone.now, nil)
  }
```

I also have a scope to get `nil` values of `product.published_on` and this works, though I want them in one scope

```
  scope :null_items, lambda {
    joins(:product).where(
      products: { published_on: nil }
    )
  }
```

Comment: Which database do you use?

Comment: @RomanAlekseiev postgres :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In [Postgresql](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-is-null/) NULL is not equal to NULL so the following expression returns false:
`NULL = NULL`

To check whether a value is NULL or not, you use the IS NULL operator instead:

`value IS NULL`

So in your case it would be something like this:

```rb
scope :not_new_items, lambda {
    joins(:product).where("products.published_on < ? OR products.published_on IS NULL", Time.zone.now)
  }
```

If you look on the query which produces ActiveRecord for `field: nil` it would be `SELECT "table_name".* FROM "table_name" WHERE "table_name"."field" IS NULL`

Comment: OOOHHHH I get it now. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

A NULL value indicates an unavailable or unassigned value. The value NULL does not equal zero (0), nor does it equal space (' '). Because the NULL value cannot be equal or unequal to any value, you cannot perform any comparison on this value by using operators such as '=' or '<>'.

So you have to replace `=` with `is`

```
  scope :not_new_items, lambda {
           joins(:product).where("products.published_on < ? OR 
      products.published_on IS ?", Time.zone.now, nil)
 }
```